# GCP & Terraform: How to find a specific google folder with random suffix in terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, directory, terraform, wildcard

I have the following issue:

As deleted resources vanish only after 30 days, I add random suffixes as part of gcp folder names.
Now in order to find and select the according folder for deploying shared VPCs and alike I am looking for the specific folders in terraform.

I tried to achieve this with

```
data "google_active_folder "dev" {
   display_name = "${var.folder_prefix}-development*"
   parent       = local.parent_id
}
```

But it seems that google_active_folder is not compatible with wildcards.

Any help or hint is appreciated!

Comment: what is the error message you are getting when you run above snippet?

Comment: Add the following as a separate question: 'Unable to upgrade the google provider version from 3.90.1 to 4.0.0 ?' - providing more information on what you have encountered. Will edit question to limit it to a specific problem, so that it will be more useful for community use.

Comment: Can you search by parent folder using the google_folders Data Source and find it that way?

Comment: @stephen.vakil I tried to, but unfortunately this doesn't work in the gcp version 3.x  and I wasn't able to upgrade the provider version higher than 3.90.1...